# Can I can add facebook audience network through mopub

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-ads-api, mopub

I am a beginner at android. I tried adding facebook ads to my app. but I couldn't success I am getting a lot of error. I heard mopub has the easy integrating solution. can I use it to show Facebook ads? how please help.

Answer (score 1):

just go to [Mopub mediation adapters on Github](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-mediation) and add the Facebook adapters to your project, you don't need to write the custom event yourself

Answer (score 0):

Although you can easily do that following the guide here: [MoPub mediation guide](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/mediation/networks/facebook/) on mediation, if I was the one here, I'd instead go with Google AdMob mediation. They support tons of ad networks, and the integration is far easier than MoPub. For AdMob, you just have to add the ad networks in the Admob console and add the SDKs for the ad networks in your app. But if you choose to go with MoPub, just follow the guide above. It is beginner friendly, and self explanatory.

Comment: i want to use mediation for native ads.